# Serialize a JSON object without property name having a list of custom object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have model as below:

```
public class CustomModel
    {        
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
    }

public class root
    {   
        public List<CustomModel> data { get; set; }
    }
```

My payload is as below:

```
List<CustomModel> cms = new List<CustomModel>();

                CustomModel cm1 = new CustomModel();
                cm1.Data1 = "a";
                cm1.Data2 = "b";
                cms.Add(cm1);

                CustomModel cm2 = new CustomModel();
                cm2.Data1 = "D";
                cm2.Data2 = "E";
                cms.Add(cm2);

                BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
                baseClass.data = cms;
```

My JSON is:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(baseClass);
```

And Result is:

```
{"data":[{"data1":"a","data2":"b"},{"data1":"D","data2":"E"}]}
```

**BUT I need:** without the "**data**" property as below:

```
{[{"data1":"a","data2":"b"},{"data1":"D","data2":"E"}]}
```

I tried the below function:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetPropertyValues<T>(T input)
            {
                return input.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(p => p.GetValue(input));
            }
```

Like

```
var value_only = GetPropertyValues(baseClass);
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value_only);
BUT it returns [[{"data1":"a","data2":"b"},{"data1":"D","data2":"E"}]]
```

Is there anywasy to do it other than manually adding? Please help.

Comment: Typo: I suppose "public class root" should be "public class BaseClass"?

Comment: Maybe make your BaseClass extend from Collection<T>, then it doesn't need that data property.

Comment: Did you try `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(baseClass.data)`?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `{[{"data1":"a","data2":"b"},{"data1":"D","data2":"E"}]}` is not valid json. In Json objects, data/values are organized by (named) properties.

However, here you seem to want a (root) Json object containing a value being Json array, but that value is not associated with a Json object property, thus not being valid Json.

If you really want invalid Json, i suggest you serialize the `List<CustomModel>` instance instead of the root model instance, resulting in a Json array, and then manually adding the surrounding `{` and `}` to the serialized Json string, thus giving you your desired invalid Json result:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(baseClass.data);
var desiredResult = "{" + json + "}";
```

Comment: Yes it is not valid json but my client needs it, and yes i have provided the the solution the way u told adding the curly brace around my result

Comment: This json is not valid

Answer (score 0):

you don't need root class (or base class you must to deside what is name. Just use

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cms);
```

PS.

And it is time to select a modern serializer.

Comment: its returns [{"data1":"a","data2":"b"},{"data1":"D","data2":"E"}] but i need a more additional {} around it.

Comment: @the-a-monir additional {} around it will make a json invalid , and it  can  not be used, it you want {} around you have to use "data"

Comment: yes, but my client needs it. he wants it nameless (last node) i.e. without 'data' property

Comment: @the-a-monir In this case I could advise the client to use an abacus.